# Is a solid sphere with a "bubble" in the middle topologically the same as a torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose there was a solid sphere or ball with radius 2 such that a sphere with radius 1 was removed from the center making a hollow cavity. A sphere with a "bubble in it" if that's easier to visualize.

Is this topologically equivalent to a torus? to a sphere? to a whole other class of shapes I'm unaware of?

Comment: No, a torus has a "hole" but a sphere-with-a-bubble has a "void": some closed loops in a torus cannot be shrunk to a point, but every sphere in a torus can, while the opposite is true for the sphere-with-a-bubble. See also [Betti number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number).

Comment: Do you mean a *ball* of radius $2$ with a *ball* of radius $1$ removed?  Spheres are hollow; balls are solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Note that A sphere $\cong$ $S^n$ which is the set of points of distance **equals** to 1 from the origin. While a Ball $\cong$ $D^n$ which is the set of all points of distance $\le 1$ from the origin. **They are different,** so be careful while describing them.

I think the following argument answers your problem.

Let $X$ denotes the space you're talking about.

---

This might be a clearer argument to show that $X\not\cong T_1$, where $T_1$ denotes the torus, but will require some knowledge from algebraic topology.

Choose $x_0\in X$ and a continuous map $\alpha:I\to X$ s.t. $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x_0$ (loop). You can always find a way to continuously deform it to a single point, so the fundamental group $\pi(X,x_0)$ is trivial, suggesting that $X$ is simply connected

However, a loop in $T_1$ that enclose the center hole cannot be deformed to a point, suggesting that $T_1$ is not simply connected. Therefore $X\not\cong T_1$.

More information, please see [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/N-sphere_is_simply_connected_for_n_greater_than_1#Proof_using_fact_.281.29) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space).

---

But, $X$ can be deformation retract to a sphere $S^2$ through a continuous map $h_t:X\to A\cong S^2$ and the inverse is an inclusion map. So  $X$ is **homotopy equivalent** to $S^2$ i.e. $X\simeq S^2$. This concept is different from homeomorphism.
[Definition of homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy)

---

to have a better understanding about those concept mentioned above, I recommend you to read *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher. You could found it on website http://gen.lib.rus.ec/

Comment: You can also find Hatcher's book on his Cornell website, it's free: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are really asking, so here are some arguments.

$X=\mathbb{B}^3 \setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{S}^2$ has two connected components, while both the sphere and the torus have one. Hence $X$ is not homotopy equivalent (the weakest notion of topologically equivalent I am aware of) to either of them. It is however to $\mathbb{S}^2 \sqcup *$.

$Y=\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{S}^2 = \mathbb{S}^2$ by definition, since $ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{S}^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

$Z = \mathbb{B}^3 \setminus \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{B}^3$ is homotopy equivalent to the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$.